# Не получаются заюзать SQL инъекцию

Tags: sql

Пытаюсь дропнуть таблицу у себя на денвере через SQL инъекцию:

```
<form method="post" action="http://test1.ru/?menu=admin&sel=rules">
 <input type="text" name="tx" value="'; DROP TABLE db_conabrul;">
 <input type="submit" value="next">
</form>
```

Как только не пробывал, не могу удалить таблицу. Тестирую на денвере, **права на удаление есть**. Выводит вот такую ошибку:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DROP TABLE db_conabrul;' WHERE id = '1'' at line 1
```

Таблицу не уделяет. Через прямой запрос в pma всё ок. Но нужно **именно через инъекцию**. Что я делаю не так?

Запрос выглядит так:

```
$db->Query("UPDATE db_conabrul SET rules = '".$_POST["tx"]."' WHERE id = '1'");
```

Comment: Если это действительно ваш локальный денвер - залоггируйте куда-нибудь склеенный SQL запрос с вашей инъекцией и посмотрите, что там не так с синтаксисом.

Comment: после инъекции нужно как минимум комментировать все следующее далее ('; DROP TABLE db_conabrul; \-\-), чтобы запрос не развалился. Местоположение не очень стандартное для подстановки вообще чего бы то ни было.

Comment: @Fike, Ваш вариант '; DROP TABLE db_conabrul; -- не сработал. Как правильно надо вообще? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Modal, дайте ваш SQL-код.  
Если нужен просто классический пример, то

    SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = ':placeholder';
+
    i do not need your result, filthy machine'; DROP TABLE users; --

должно сработать.

Comment: @Fike, не пашет. Вот посмотрите запрос: >>$db->Query("UPDATE db_conabrul SET rules = '".$_POST["tx"]."' WHERE id = '1'");

Comment: @Nofate ♦, 'DROP TABLE db_conabrul; ну и так например тоже не работает. Если не затруднит, то скажите как правильно. А то я пока додумаюсь, год пройдёт.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
"UPDATE db_conabrul SET rules = '".$_POST["tx"]."' WHERE id = '1'"

$_POST["tx"]=',id=(select IF((DROP TABLE db_conabrul)=1,1,1))),id='1
```

на выходе имеем:

```
UPDATE db_conabrul SET rules = '',id=(select IF((DROP TABLE db_conabrul)=1,1,1))), id='1' WHERE id = '1';
```

валидный SQL запрос с подзапросом... насчет валидности не тестил но куда копать.. думаю будет понятно....

Если даже после такого примера вам непонятно то советую почитать литературу сначала, по MySQL например... а то, что не работает копипастом - скорее всего так... я лишь направление указал)

1. Выше вам уже указали что выполнить 2 запроса в 1 строку нельзя!
2. Исходя из того, что написано выше, вам нужно подставить валидные данные для запроса rules = '' т.е. начинать иньекцию с ВАЛИДНЫХ данных для этого запроса
3. далее "закрыть" ковычку
4. далее исхитрится и вставить запрос ИНЬЕКЦИИ так чтобы он был подзапросом, что то возвращал в реальных условиях, например как в моем примере(я не в курсе что можно у вас ставить в id) моя иньекция запишет(сделает) Set ID=1, цифра 1 получается подзапросом с иньекцией (select IF((DROP TABLE db_conabrul),1,1)) вот так по идее сработает) там где записано 1,1 - то что вернет подзапрос...
5. Думаю в вашем случае MYSQL не даст УДАЛИТЬ таблицу в которой ведется UPDATE т.к. таблица лочена(хотя не уверен), пробуйте удалить другу таблицу.
6. Думайте... :)

Comment: @ToRcH565, невалид. Я не знаю в какую сторону копать, поэтому и спрашиваю тут..

Comment: Поправил ответ.

Answer (score 4):

А что находится "под капотом" $db->Query()? Если что-то вроде mysql_query() -- то выполнить несколько запросов за 1 раз не получится:

> mysql_query() sends a unique query (**multiple queries are not supported**) to the currently active database on the server that's associated with the specified link_identifier.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: @ModaL откуда столько злости?

Comment: @IVsevolod, не по теме потому что ответы. Хочу научиться >< Может вы знаете как просто дропнуть таблицу через инъекцию $db->Query("UPDATE db_conabrul SET rules = '".$_POST["tx"]."' WHERE id = '1'"); ? :D

Comment: @ModaL вполне таки может и по теме, так как, если функция не способна выполнить 2 запроса из входной строки, то дропнуть таблицу как раз таки и не получиться, т.к. это будет второй запрос. А вообще тут уже советовали. 

> *попробуйте в запросе выполнить тот запрос, который получается при склеивании*, выявить ошибки и двинуться в нужном направлении )

Comment: @IVsevolod, как понять "при склеивании"? Не догоняю :(

Comment: @ModaL, у вас есть параметризованный запрос 

    $db->Query("UPDATE db_conabrul SET rules = '".$_POST["tx"]."' WHERE id = '1'");

Скрипт подставит туда ваш фрагмент из `tx`. В итоге в базу пойдет запрос, склеенный (конкатенированный, интерполированный) из нескольких строк. Т.е. попробуйте немного изменить код:

    $my_query = "UPDATE db_conabrul SET rules = '".$_POST["tx"]."' WHERE id = '1'"
    $db->Query($my_query);

и посмотреть, что в итоге находится в `$my_query` (через `echo`, `var_dump`, как угодно). Ну и нам покажите.

Comment: @Nofate ♦, Ну получается вот так: UPDATE db_conabrul SET rules = ''; DROP TABLE db_conabrul;' WHERE id = '1'sadsd'

Comment: >  DROP TABLE db_conabrul;' WHERE id = '1'

@ModaL, из этого получается, что у вас после `db_conabrul;` ненужная кавычка.